# Inspect collections of GenericEntities inside a GenericEntity

Tags: hiconic

I have a Property `p` of a GenericEntity `entity` and know it is a collection (in my case always a List). It is a List of other GenericEntities, thus:

```
GenericModelType type = p.getType();

if (type.isCollection() && type.areEntitiesReachable()) {
 // I am here
  
}
```

How can I test whether the instance of a collection (`p.get(entity)` just returns `Object`) is

1. a collection of what type exactly
2. empty, or how many etries it has,
3. the actual type of the elements of the collection
4. e.g. the first element of such a collection.

I am basically stuck in converting `p.get(entity)` into a useful instance that I can then actually inspect.